# Colouring of $n$ dimensional Euclidean space.

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

If a $n$ dimensional Euclidean space is divided by $n-1$ dimensional planes then what is the minimum number of colors required to color the sectors such that no two neighboring sectors are of same color.

Comment: If the planes are parallel then you can colour alternate $n-1$ spaces with just $2$ colours.

Comment: Why is it not true for any set of planes?

Comment: Well if 3 planes are all at right angles to each other, they divide 8 separate spaces which come together as in the origin of a 3-dimensional space separated into positive and negative x,y, and z. I can't see how 8 spaces can come together at some vertex and be divided into 2 colours such that no two sections are the same colour.

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem for lines in a plane? The more general version has almost exactly the same solution.

Comment: @RobertFrost I'm assuming that only regions that share an $(n-1)$-dimensional face (that is, regions separated by only one of the hyperplanes) are considered to be adjacent.